# JavaScript regular expressions - matching only whole occurrences of the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that searches for `@{<integer>}` and should only return a match if this is a complete word in itself.
E.g., `Hello @{1}` should return the match but `Hello@{1}` or `@{1}Hello` should not return match.

Furthermore, `Hello @{1}!` should return but `Hello @{1}!adkjnasj` should not return.

[Regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/f6LD25/5)

I have tried using `\b` but that doesn't seem to work for me.
I have tried advanced matches with `?:`, but that still returns the spaces in the match [RegEx with ?:](https://regex101.com/r/f6LD25/8)

I want the match to only be `@{1}` - without any spaces.

---

Edit:

Notice that \b doesnt work for me. [RegEx with \b](https://regex101.com/r/f6LD25/10)

This isn't a duplicate of the above solution because "?<=" doesn't work in JavaScript.

Comment: try this - `[^\w]@\{\d+\}[^\w]`

Comment: @AnkushRathi if you notice [here](https://regex101.com/r/f6LD25/11) - the full string match contains extra things that I don't want to be matched.

Comment: do you mean the spaces ?

Comment: Yes, and punctuations..